# Yq to parse yaml failing because of list keys

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, yq

I have a template like below

```
Version: "2012-10-17"
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Principal:
      Service:
        - "xyz.amazonaws.com"
    Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
```

I want to extract "xyz.amazonaws.com" using yaml command. How can I do that ?
It's not responding because of list key - "- Effect: Allow"

Comment: Which `yq` version are you using? The Python version(https://pypi.org/project/yq/) or the Go version (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

Comment: I am using mikefarah version 3

Answer (score 0):

```
yq r <yaml document> Version.[Effect==Allow].Action
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context why you think this is an answer to the question. See also [answer].